# Have a problem editing my database. It wont change data when I edit it on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, edit

New to PHP. I'm making a web application. I was trying to make some editable tables in which you can change data directly and those changes then would be saved in database. Found some solutions on net, but I have trouble implement it. Can't find where I'm wrong. Appreciate any help.

This is my PHP code with  editable tables:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Slavoljub">
    <meta name="description" content="Sajt za obradu podataka na farmama">
    <title>Prasence</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/pigicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&family=Titan+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Uključuje jQuery i BootStrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tabledit.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilovi.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Prasence</h1>
    <div class="login">
        <a class="prijava" href="login.php">Prijava</a>
        <a class="prijava" href="signUp.php">Registracija</a>
    </div>
</header>
<nav>
    <div class="navig">
        <a href="index.php">Početna</a>
        <a href="sow.php">Krmače</a>
        <a href="barn.php">Štale</a>
        <a href="data.php">Podaci</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";

    if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION["user_id"];

        if (isset($_POST["farrowAll"])) {
            $sql = "SELECT sowNumber, cycleNumber, penNumber, pigletBornNumber, livePigletBorn, farrowingDate FROM farrowing WHERE userId = '$userId'";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if ($result) {
                echo '<table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">';
                echo '<tr>
                        <th>Korisnik</th>
                        <th>Broj krmače</th>
                        <th>Broj ciklusa</th>
                        <th>Broj boksa</th>
                        <th>Broj prasadi pri rođenju</th>
                        <th>Broj žive prasadi pri rođenju</th>
                        <th>Datum prašenja</th>
                      </tr>';

                $totalPigletBorn = 0; // Inicijalizacija varijable za ukupan broj prasadi
                $totalLivePigletBorn = 0;

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $userId . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['sowNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['cycleNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['penNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['pigletBornNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['livePigletBorn'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['farrowingDate'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    $totalPigletBorn += $row['pigletBornNumber'];
                    $totalLivePigletBorn += $row['livePigletBorn'];
                }

                // Prikazuje ukupan broj prasadi ispod tabele
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td colspan="3"></td>';
                echo '<td>Total : ' . $totalPigletBorn . '</td>';
                echo '<td>Total : ' . $totalLivePigletBorn . '</td>';
                echo '<td colspan="2"></td>';
                echo '</tr>';

                echo '</table>';
                $result->close();
            } else {
                echo "Greška pri izvršavanju upita: " . $mysqli->error;
            }
        } else if (isset($_POST["farrowCurrent"])) {
            $sql = "SELECT sowNumber, cycleNumber, penNumber, pigletBornNumber, livePigletBorn, farrowingDate FROM farrowing WHERE userId = '$userId' AND currentInFarrHouse = 1";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if ($result) {
                echo '<table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">';
                echo '<tr>
                     <th>Korisnik</th>
                        <th>Broj krmače</th>
                        <th>Broj ciklusa</th>
                        <th>Broj boksa</th>
                        <th>Broj prasadi pri rođenju</th>
                        <th>Broj žive prasadi pri rođenju</th>
                        <th>Datum prašenja</th>
                      </tr>';

                $totalPigletBorn = 0; // Inicijalizacija varijable za ukupan broj prasadi
                $totalLivePigletBorn = 0;

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $userId . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['sowNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['cycleNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['penNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['pigletBornNumber'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['livePigletBorn'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['farrowingDate'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    $totalPigletBorn += $row['pigletBornNumber'];
                    $totalLivePigletBorn += $row['livePigletBorn'];
                }

                // Prikazuje ukupan broj prasadi ispod tabele
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td colspan="3"></td>';
                echo '<td>Total : ' . $totalPigletBorn . '</td>';
                echo '<td>Total : ' . $totalLivePigletBorn . '</td>';
                echo '<td colspan="2"></td>';
                echo '</tr>';

                echo '</table>';
                $result->close();
            } else {
                echo "Error executing the SQL query: " . $mysqli->error;
            }
        } else {
            echo "Greška pri unosu podataka";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Morate se ulogovati kako biste unosili podatke";
    }
    ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom_table_edit.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is javascript file I linked in head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
```

Other javascript file is , and there is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#data_table").Tabledit({
    deleteButton: false,
    editButton: false,
    columns: {
      identifier: [0, "userId"],
      editable: [
        [1, "sowNumber"],
        [2, "cycleNumber"],
        [3, "penNumber"],
        [4, "sectionNumber"],
        [5, "pigletBornNumber"],
        [6, "livePigletBorn"],
        [7, "farrowingDate"],
      ],
    },
    hideIdentifier: true,
    url: "live_edit.php",
  });
});
```

Here is the code for live_edit.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once("connection.php");

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

if ($input['action'] == 'edit') {
    $update_field = '';

    if (isset($input['userId'])) {
        $update_field .= "userId='" . $input['userId'] . "'";
    } else if (isset($input['sowNumber'])) {
        $update_field .= "sowNumber='" . $input['sowNumber'] . "'";
    } else if (isset($input['cycleNumber'])) {
        $update_field .= "cycleNumber='" . $input['cycleNumber'] . "'";
    } else if (isset($input['penNumber'])) {
        $update_field .= "penNumber='" . $input['penNumber'] . "'";
    } else if (isset($input['sectionNumber'])) {
        $update_field .= "sectionNumber='" . $input['sectionNumber'] . "'";
    } else if (isset($input['pigletBornNumber'])) {
        $update_field .= "pigletBornNumber='" . $input['pigletBornNumber'] . "'";
    } else if (isset($input['livePigletBorn'])) {
        $update_field .= "livePigletBorn='" . $input['livePigletBorn'] . "'";
    } else if (isset($input['farrowingDate'])) {
        $update_field .= "farrowingDate='" . $input['farrowingDate'] . "'";
    }

    if ($update_field && $input['id']) {
        $sql_query = "UPDATE farrowing SET $update_field WHERE userId='" . $input['userId'] . "'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);

        if (!$result) {
            echo "Error executing the SQL query: " . $mysqli->error;
            die("database error:" . $mysqli->error);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It wont update the database

Comment: What exactly is your `Tabledit` script there sending? Does it only post _one_ parameter for the field that has actually changed - or does it post one for each of them, including even the unchanged fields? If it is the latter - then your else-if logic there stops it processing any parameters after the first one, `userId`. And since that one probably never changes, you will be firing an UPDATE statement that only attempts to set the userId to the value it already had.

Answer (score -2):

IN THE LIVE_EDIT.PHP FILE, IN THE VARIABLE WHERE YOU POPULATE THE ATTRIBUTE WITH THE FIELDS, THERE IS A COMMA BETWEEN ONE FIELD AND THE OTHER, EXAMPLE: UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;

Comment: There is no "one field and the other", there is only _one_ `field='value'` - it's all else-ifs, so not more than one of the conditions can have any effect at the same time.

Comment: Post the error you produce